# C++ skipping on cin.getline

Tags: c++

i have a problem with input char to my program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int  main()
{
int choise;
char word[81];


cin >> choise;
cout << "enter the word:" << endl;
cin.getline(word, 81);

return 0;
}
```

the visual studio open the input to "choise" 
but skip on cin.getline (it the same if i replace it with gets_s).

i tried to write
cin.get(); before the "getline"...
but then  the program not get's the first char
(if i put 'aa' it get 'a')
what can i do?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its because you entered a newline for the program to accept the integer you entered for `choice`, the that newline is not extracted from the buffer, leaving it to be read in your next input operation. The `getline` call reads that left-over newline, and is happy with that.

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem. The first and most obvious is to use `std::string` for the `word` variable, and then use the normal input operator `>>` as that will skip leading whitespace (which includes newline).

Another solution is to tell the input stream to [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) until and including a newline. The linked reference has an example on how to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

After entering the integer you press enter, and this enter input is left in the buffer area and used as the next input for getline and the computer assumes you're done.
add this line before `getline` statement and re- compile it.
`cin.ignore()`.

Comment: ohhhi put cin.ignore(); and now it ok
but tell me. why when i put cin.get(); before the "getline"  then the program not get's the first char (if i put 'aa' it get 'a')

Comment: i do not understand exactly what you mean there because when i add the `cin.get();` statement, the program does not exhibit those behaviors you're saying. explain more or ask another question.